# How can I delete/remove a top level folder from vscode Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS.Code explorer, I have a directory being listed that I don't want. It points to an old branch.
Right-click menu does not have a remove/delete option and the del key does nothing for folders evidently.

How can I remove this folder from explorer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't This Folder is the root of the project u choose

[image]

Comment: Ok, then how do I remove this project? I don't see any terminology referring to anything called a project though.

Comment: I guess this is a problem with my understanding of how vscode manages folders/workspaces. Indeed, I am not able to delete the folder from vscode, and will, therefore, mark this answer as accepted since it seems to be true.

Comment: So you want to manage an another project and not this one right ? 
Go to File > Open Folder ; and choose the correct one.
Or create a new one

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the top-level folder.
2. File -> Close Folder

That will not delete the folder from disk, but it will remove it from vscode explorer.